# How access key of key of object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a function that would have access to a key that is inside an object that is inside another object.

I've been reading through the TS Documentation but I believe I am not using the correct generics on my function, for Example:

```
interface A {
  abc: number
  acd: number
}
interface B {
  bcd: number
  bde: number
}
interface C {
  cde: number
  cef: number
}
interface Data {
  a: A
  b: B
  c: C
}

const data: Data = {
  a: {
    abc: 1,
    acd: 2
  },
  b: {
    bcd: 3,
    bde: 4
  },
  c: {
    cde: 5,
    cef: 6
  }
}

const getItem = <T extends keyof Data, K extends keyof T>(
    category: T,
    item: K
  ) => {
    console.log(data[category][item]) // ERROR: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'Data[T]'.ts(2536)
  }
```

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you don't want `K` to index into `T` (which is itself a key type), but into the property of `Data` at the index `T`.  To represent the type of a property with key `P` of an object of type `O`, you need a [lookup (or indexed access) type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) using bracket notation: `O[P]`.  In your case, the property of an object of type `Data` at an index of type `T` has type `Data[T]`.  So `K` should extend not `T` but `Data[T]`:

```
const getItem = <T extends keyof Data, K extends keyof Data[T]>(
    category: T,
    item: K
) => {
    console.log(data[category][item]);
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XAIwQC5kQBXAWwOhz0QBNSLraBfLUSWRFAIUx1cRJmSo0oQ5AQYRm49p3DR4SZAGFBeZAlnzWk7Uhj6JWDlxW9kAEThg4W+qVRSCpPlJIbzOLAgB7EABnMGQGezhSOwdkAF4nXCjE7XwiUgBGABopbUZSACYpNhztdxSy3VIAZlLU4T1kABZiutxvbHr2xoBWNtTjUgA2Yt9-INDkAHMIMABJSEp45AAeABVkCAAPSBAGYOQAawgATwCYW0is5ABpTZ2IPYPjs4uYuABtNYBdAD4ACi89ggUwCUBOpDW-WAi1INywAEp4r8UoEQgEADYQAB0GICU3+EQcHwQwNB4O+HxhEEo3wRAG5fEA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz that is absolutely correct, I couldn't see it before but it makes perfect sense!
Cheers :)